# UIApplicationDelegate not called in Xcode AppDelegate file generated by Unity3d

Tags: objective-c, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a game developed in Unity3d and I export it to be in Xcode form, and the `UIApplication` delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the iPhone_target2AppDelegate.m file generated by Unity3d are not called, I try to put some code in this method by showing a `UIAlertView`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
  {
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"It Works" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
// Override point for customization after app launch    
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }
```

but nothing show up on the screen !

any help please

Solved : look at the bottom of the post :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not the Unity part! Have you tried setting a simple breakpoint to see if it is hit? Or an NSLog statement? Not sure if UIAlterview will show up in applicationDidFinishLaunching as not even the window has been displayed on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it, it seems that the AppController.h+.m is the one response for handling the `UIApplication` delegates, and if you take a look at the AppController.m file you will see that they are already exist like the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and others.

Also I put some code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if the `UIAlertView` wouldn't show on the AppDelegate... A `NSLog` is more than enough.

Comment: Why? Because the main window hasn't been created yet? I thought alert views were displayed on a 'system' window, above and beyond the app...?

Comment: I am guessing with would expect an `UIView` where it could be rendered.

Comment: I'm quite sure alert views are managed by the system, and they lie in another window above your app's one (they are 'system modal'). That's why you can't overlay anything on top of them.

Comment: Agreed NSLog is the way to go when debugging (alert is overkill and also blocks the UI)